# Could someone explain what it means that temperature is a lagrange multiplier of energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I have looked online but I couldn't find anything that explains this definition

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/427551/is-temperature-a-lagrange-multiplier-of-energy  . This may help you.

Answer (score 4):

Consider  the entropy 
$$
S=- \int \rho\ln \rho \,d^npd^nq
$$
where $d^npd^nq$ is the phase-space element of volume and $\rho$ the phase-space probability density. We seek to maximize the entropy  subject to the constraints 
$$
1=\int \rho\, d^npd^nq, \qquad E= \int \rho H(p,q) \,d^npd^nq.
$$
To deal with the first and second constraint we introduce Lagrange multipliers $1+\alpha$ and $\beta$ repsectively, so that the stationarity condition  becomes 
$$
0= \delta\left\{\int(-\rho\ln \rho+(1+\alpha)\rho- \beta\rho H(p,q) )d^nd^nq\right\}\\
= \int(-\ln \rho+\alpha- \beta H(p,q))  \delta \rho \, d^nd^nq.
$$
The stationary point is therefore 
$$
\rho(p,q) = e^{\alpha-\beta H(p,q)}
$$
which, with $\beta=1/kT$, is the canonical distribution.

Comment: Why in the variation integral an additional $\rho$ does appear as coefficient of the Hamiltonian constraint ? Was it forgotten in the energy constraint above ?

Comment: @ Frederic Thomas The "$1$" in $1+\alpha$ cancells agains the $\delta(\rho\ln\rho) = (\ln \rho +1)\delta \rho$. Ah! That's not what you are asking. I see my error. Yes it was forgotten. Will edit!

Comment: I see, nice demonstration.